# What are the patterns on this solar panel?

Tags: orion-spacecraft, artemis-1

What are the patterns on this solar panel?

I'm specifically referring to the apparently random routing of (some of) the wires.

I don't suppose that they're random or unintentional, so I can only assume that it's by design? In which case for what purpose?

This is a crop from a photo of Artemis' Orion capsule passing the moon.

[image: Solr Panel Wiring]

Comment: The middle white one snaking to the end is for the gopro4-origin cameras used for selfies

Comment: Cables on the backside of the solar array. There seem to be several "things" installed between the cells, see this front-side view: https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasaorion/52518189065/in/photostream/

Comment: Each of the straight wires is connected to a cell string on the front, either to the high voltage side or the low end. The cell strings often do not form neat patterns on the front side, and that means the wiring on the back side will look random.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The design of the SAW is based on an improved version of the Solar Array Wings that flew on the ESA ATV, a cargo resupply and reboost vehicle for the ISS, through 5 flights from 2008 to 2015. (in fact most of the service module is a mission-specific version inheriting some aspects of the same module used in the ATV, which went some way to improve its chances of being selected in powering Orion, as it was already flight proven)

[image]

This is the back side of the ATV wing, same as you see in your picture of the Orion/ESA SM SAW. That side does not have (triple junction GaAs solar cells forming nine sections of solar cell strings) sun-facing solar cells.

Ignore this being white, this was protection for operations in LEO that exposed the panels to erosive atomic oxygen encountered - scant oxygen molecules at the top of the atmosphere are split into individual atoms by ultraviolet radiation (aka ATOX erosion).

The various electrical cables on the back of the  Carbon Fiber Reinforced Polymer rigid panels are fixed in wavy lines to help withstand physical thermo-elastic induced in orbit stress due to the difference in the coefficient of thermal expansion between the solar panels and the copper wires.

Flexprints are applied between panels. These flat, double isolated flexible electrical circuits are connected to dedicated flexprint connector parts, which are bolted to the edge members of neighbouring panels.

To shield the CFRP face sheets electrically from the cells a layer of kapton is added to the top side of the panel.

Any panel bracketry are glued to the uniform substrate afterwards. High conductive carbon fibres are selected to use the panels rear side as a radiator cooler.

Solar cells are connected together and protected by integral shunt diodes between the cells as well as one blocking diode per string. Additionally the panel is protected by a grounding circuit and a bleed resistor towards the spacecraft.

In between the solar cell strings optical solar reflectors (OSRs) are applied.

Four guide holes per panel are for the pin that keeps them aligned (along with a kevlar strap that gets cut on command to release) when folded in stowed position.

The panel edges are covered by white coated titanium called Edge shields.

At the yoke, wire bundles are protected by glass fabric Nextel sleeving.

The white cabling snaking towards the end, ending in a white box, is for the cameras mounted at the end of each wing:

[image]

https://www.airbus.com/en/OrionESM

https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Highlights/Orion

https://www.nasa.gov/feature/orion-solar-array-wing-deployment-test-is-a-success-0

Comment: So, briefly: thermal expansion.  So obvious in hindsight!
FYI a few high-res photos of the panels illistrating this answer's details are at https://newatlas.com/orion-solar-panels-test/42118/#gallery:1

Comment: Amazing answer - thank you.